# Modify className when element is clicked in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a menu bar in ReactJS which has some basic routing functionality. The JSX for the component is as follows:

```
class TopBar extends Component {
  state = {
    menus: [{id:0,menu:"Home"}, {id:1,menu:"Contact"}, {id:2,menu:"About"}]
  }
  addClass = e => {
    console.log("Addclass "+ e.target);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
                <div>  
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                              {this.state.menus.map((menu,index) =>
                                    <li className="nav-item ng-star-inserted">
                                      <a className={`nav-link ${'active'}`} id={"sample"+ menu.id} onClick={this.addClass} > 
                                        <Link to={menu.menu}> {menu.menu} </Link>
                                      </a>
                                    </li>
                                )}
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </nav>

          <Route path="/home" exact component={
            Home
          } />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={
           Contact
          } />
          <Route path="/about" exact component={
            About
          } />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS :

```
.navbar .nav-link.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fdd92d;
}
```

When I click on a particular menu (Home/Contact/About) I want `active` class appended to that particular menu. I have added `onClick` event and tried to pass `id` attribute to it.
 But the `id` is blank in the debugger.
[image]

How can I add the `active` className once the menu is clicked?

Comment: you can use `NavLink` already has activeClass for `router`

Comment: @Dkouk yes, but is there a way to do it without using `NavLink`?

Comment: yes but you need to use a local state and tie that in with the index of the menu loop. eg `onClick={() => this.setState({active: index})} className={this.state.active === index ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link'}`

Comment: Thanks @DimitarChristoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work using your way, you will have to store `isActive` key for each menu object. Your `addClass()` function should be like this:

```
addClass = e => {
  this.setState({
    menus: this.state.menus.map(menu => ({
      ...menu,
      isActive: e.target.id == menu.id
    }))
  })
}
```

Each time addClass is called, we go through each menu object, if the menu's id match the ID user has clicked, we give it `isActive: true`, else we set it to false. And of course we use `.map` to return a new set of menus since we can't mutate `this.state.menus` directly.

Then we can check whether a menu is active or not by checking its `isActive` key:

```
{
  this.state.menus.map(menu =>
    <a
      className={`nav ${menu.isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}
      id={menu.id}
      onClick={this.addClass}
    >
      {menu.menu}
    </a>
  )
}
```

---

Built this working snippet for you:

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  state = {
    menus: [{id:0,menu:"Home"}, {id:1,menu:"Contact"}, {id:2,menu:"About"}]
  }

  addClass = e => {
    this.setState({
      menus: this.state.menus.map(menu => ({
        ...menu,
        isActive: e.target.id == menu.id
      }))
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.menus.map(menu =>
            <a
              style={{color: menu.isActive ? 'red' : 'black'}}
              className={`nav ${menu.isActive ? 'active' : ''}`}
              id={menu.id}
              onClick={this.addClass}
            >
              {menu.menu}
            </a>
          )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're better off using the react-router-dom's `NavLink` stuff instead.

```
<NavLink to={menu.menu} activeClassName='active' className='nav-link'>
  {menu.menu}
</NavLink>
```

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md

Answer (score 0):

Here is example for your reference

```
import * as React from "react";

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import  styles from "./NavigationMenu.css";

 function NavigationMenu() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
       <ul className={styles.nav}>
         <li>
          <NavLink to="/home" activeClassName={styles.active}>
             Home
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
         <NavLink to="/contacts" activeClassName={styles.active}>
            Contacts
         </NavLink>
        </li>
       <li>
         <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName={styles.active}>
           About
         </NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default NavigationMenu;
```

And just add .active class in css file or if you want to refactor it you can create NavigationItem component as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import classes from './NavigationItem.css';

const navigationItem = ( props ) => (
   <li className={classes.NavigationItem}>
    <NavLink 
        to={props.link}
        exact={props.exact}
        activeClassName={classes.active}>{props.children}</NavLink>
  </li>
);

export default navigationItem;
```

`<NavLink>` will automatically add active class to current active link or page